# Generate word's list from two CSV files and export to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to use PowerShell to import two CSV files, one CSV is called accts and one is called names. The accts file has 8 numbers and the names files has 4 names. I need to output a combination where the end goal is to output a list of 32 words with the prefix of STX. I'll take this list of 32 and create 32 AD objects. Ideally I need to also run a check to see if the word/AD object already exists.

```
accts: 12345 23456 34567 45678 56789 67890 78901 89012
```

```
names: john dave joe mike
```

Output should be:

```
stx-12345-john
stx-23456-john
stx-34567-john
stx-45678-john
stx-56789-john
stx-67890-john
stx-78901-john
stx-89012-john
stx-12345-dave
stx-23456-dave
stx-34567-dave
stx-45678-dave
stx-56789-dave
stx-67890-dave
stx-78901-dave
stx-89012-dave
etc.
```

I've thought about trying to use arrays, but perhaps that would be to complex. Any advice?

Comment: Where's the code you're having a problem with?

Comment: For a start: `ForEach ( $Name in (Import-Csv Names.csv)){ForEach ( $Acct in (Import-Csv Accts.csv)){"stx-{0}-{1}" -f $Acct.Accts,$Name.Names}}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm i feel like you shouldn't be working on an AD with Powershell if this is to far stretched for you at this time. Yes you would use arrays and just loop through them.

So i've exploded my code as much as i can so you can learn the logic behind it.

```
$accts = @("12345","23456","34567","45678","56789","67890","78901","89012")
$names = @("john","dave","joe","mike")
$adobject = @()

foreach($n in $names){
    # for each name, go through the accts and add the prefix
    foreach($a in $accts){
        #store all items in an array
        $adobject += "stx-"+$a+"-"+$n 
    }
}
cls
# go through your array you just created
foreach($o in $adobject){
    if(get-aduser $o){
        Write-host "user $o already exists"
    }else{
        new-aduser $o #create user
    }
}
```

Little tasks like this are the best way to learn coding and logic. You should be able to translate this to using CSV's.

Comment: I agree that it why I was trying to figure out the group name creation first, before messing with AD.

Comment: and thanks for getting me through my brain cramp. :)

Comment: Why would adding the following cause multiple copies of the same name to appear in the screen output/csv file:
        $mergedfile = $adobject | add-content -path "C:\mergedlist.csv"